# Отправить Cookies методом urlib.request?

Tags: python, cookie

Пробую отправить post запрос со своими данными, мне нужно получить cookies от первого обращения к серверу. Полученные значения поставить в второй запрос содержащий уже измененный header и user agent.

```
    import requests
import time
from lxml import html
import re
import json
source = ['https://chatur', 'bate.com/auth/login/']
print(source[0]+source[1])
print(source[0]+"bate.com")
response = requests.get(source[0]+source[1])

#print(response.content)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
csrf = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/form/input/@value')
print(csrf[1])

print(response.headers.get('Set-Cookie'))
jes = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
ksrf = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
result = re.findall(r'csrftoken=\w+', ksrf)
results = re.findall(r'\w+', str(result))
print(csrf[1], results[1])

print(response.headers.get('Server'))

###############
###############
url = source[0]+source[1]
headers = {
#':authority': 'chaturbate.com',
#':method': 'POST',
#':path': '/auth/login/',
#':scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'ru,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'content-length': '122',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'cookie': ksrf,
'origin': source[0]+'bate.com',
'referer': source[0]+source[1],
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 YaBrowser/19.12.2.252 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}    
data = 'next=&csrfmiddlewaretoken={csrf[1]}}&username=thorix0&password=Lovacska00&g-recaptcha-response=03AGdBq24NntPLGWn_DrO_3PDWYzO3Ak8bcJnGfj5jj5ThGAQu51lHYDroH11vzDIgVU-8WlbdSqbQMA3n8ERyB3oDq_uY2Kkpgti_rnQeuAC9Q4sBlmYJFtoh7St4um6bjrSADh_TIIlinEj2t8udNAPhxevlowvOvyRmGxM2oIjhJHkPRSQin8Tzsnfu-bOeuISY3_jAI1Q5LR2j_SqhmqhXCLmcG5pGKYgJ2Szyi5AqNhmelhx1dYTvnUdLPHzq-bhSDepzVNBi_rJflsoxnJloP4CdA4j-Vw5gcHz5snLUpSwgt8-uN1Q3k2cUZs_Gx3H57w7EnyscjQIal67vcv1vaW33s5ciS7bgHfrL0EtzW7Cir97I9ZW96drv-pLSTLabzBcOJu5P'
res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers,  )
print(res.status_code)
print(res.history)
print(str(res.text))
```

Comment: Код странный, зачем вы используете urllib и requests одновременно?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете просто взять заголовки ответа и пихнуть их в запрос. Потому что в заголовках ответа содержится заголовок присущий только ответу `Set-Cookie`, который ставится индивидуально для каждой из куки. Вам нужно получить все куки которые передает вам сервер и поставить их в заголовок `Cookies` вашего запроса. Если вы используете библиотеку `requests`, то вы можете воспользоваться классом сессий, который будет делать все за вас, а именно держать куки в актуальном состоянии и отправлять их на сервер.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
headers = {
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Origin': 'https://chaturbate.com',
'Referer': 'https://chaturbate.com/auth/login/',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'}    
resp = session.post(..., headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
# теперь запросы session будут отправлять куки полученные при попытке авторизоваться
```

Не понятно только для чего тут еще и urllib.
И еще не понятно вы пытаетесь получить CSRF токен и никак его не используете, он отправляется не в куках, если что, он отправляется в теле пост запроса.

Comment: Правлен код, не понятно как пройти авторизацию